# pcl_ros bag_to_pcd not found

Tags: ros, pcl, bag-to-pcd, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a full install of ROS Groovy and am trying to get point clouds from bag files. When I attempt to run bag_to_pcd I the following error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named bag_to_pcd below /opt/ros/groovy/share/pcl_ros
```

In fact, none of the pcl_ros nodes listed in the [documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros?distro=groovy#ROS_nodes) are there. Have they moved somewhere else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54132/pcl_ros-bag_to_pcd-not-found/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-03**:
please provide some more information. Did you compile from source or use a prebuilt binary? Does /opt/ros/groovy/pcl_ros exist maybe it is inside the package perception_pcl

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-03**:
I just did the standard Desktop-Full install using `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full`. The pcl_ros directory does exist, but there are only two XML files in it and a cmake directory. If I run `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-pcl-ros` it just tells me it's already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They install in /opt/ros/groovy/bin. That should be directly accessible from your shell $PATH, if it was set up correctly, but it is not the correct place for **rosrun** to find it.

This looks like a bug. Several packages, converted to catkin, are mistakenly installing executables in inappropriate places. You should probably [open an issue](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues) to get that resolved.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-05**:
Right on. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/5